# Continuing issue installing GDAL for use with Python (Mac User)

Tags: python, anaconda, conda, gdal

For an upcoming research project I am going to need to use Python with GIS data (mostly rasters). I have experience using Matlab and R; however, Python is still a relative unknown to me. I've been able to get Anaconda on my machine and download the requisite packages I needed and import them successfully (e.g. Richdem); however, gdal has been a continuous pain.

```
import gdal
```

in Spyder results in...

```
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/matthew/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/osgeo/_gdal.cpython-36m-darwin.so, 2): Library not loaded: @rpath/libfontconfig.1.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/matthew/anaconda3/lib/libpoppler.78.dylib
  Reason: Incompatible library version: libpoppler.78.dylib requires version 14.0.0 or later, but libfontconfig.1.dylib provides version 13.0.0
```

I have tried:
1) updating conda
2) updating anaconda
3) updating python
4) installing GDAl through pip
5) reinstalling GDAL with conda-forge

conda list gdal

```
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
gdal                      2.4.1            py36h7eb7563_3    conda-forge
libgdal                   2.4.1                h1405c63_3    conda-forge
```

conda info

```
active environment : None
       user config file : /Users/matthew/.condarc
 populated config files : /Users/matthew/.condarc
          conda version : 4.6.14
    conda-build version : 3.17.8
         python version : 3.6.8.final.0
       base environment : /Users/matthew/anaconda3  (writable)
           channel URLs : https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/osx-64
                          https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/noarch
          package cache : /Users/matthew/anaconda3/pkgs
                          /Users/matthew/.conda/pkgs
       envs directories : /Users/matthew/anaconda3/envs
                          /Users/matthew/.conda/envs
               platform : osx-64
             user-agent : conda/4.6.14 requests/2.22.0 CPython/3.6.8 Darwin/17.6.0 OSX/10.13.5
                UID:GID : 501:20
             netrc file : None
           offline mode : False
```

I've spent several hours googling and looking around the Stack Exchange before posting here.  I would love some insights and any thoughts anyone may have on how to resolve this issue.

Comment: Anyone have any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

I see this is an old question but hopefully it helps others. The proper import would be

```
from osgeo import gdal
```

rather than

```
import gdal
```